# Count how much markets have some product

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Count how much markets have some product.

### The problem

The query is returning me just the first result and I want the `inMarketsQuantity` of each product.

### The scenario

This is the query:

```
Select product.Name As productName, 
       Count(marketProducts.ProductId) As inMarketsQuantity
From products As product
Join market_products As marketProducts On product.Id = marketProducts.ProductId
Join markets As market On marketProducts.MarketId = market.Id
```

This is the result:

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| productName   | inMarketsQuantity |
+---------------+-------------------+
| Playstation 3 | 15                |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

And this is what I'm expecting:

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| productName   | inMarketsQuantity |
+---------------+-------------------+
| Playstation 3 | 10                |
+---------------+-------------------+
| Xbox          | 5                 |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

### What I've already tried

I've already tried the following query, but I'm getting a **SQL Error (1064)**:

```
Select product.Name As productName, 
       Distinct(Count(marketProducts.ProductId)) As inMarketsQuantity

[...]
```

Comment: I believe it must be *how many* instead of *how much*, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with group by `ProductId`:

```
Select product.Name As productName,
    Count(marketProducts.ProductId) As inMarketsQuantity
From products As product
    Join market_products As marketProducts On product.Id = marketProducts.ProductId
    Join markets As market On marketProducts.MarketId = market.Id
GROUP BY marketProducts.ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select product.Name As productName, 
       Count(marketProducts.ProductId) As inMarketsQuantity
From products As product
Join market_products As marketProducts On product.Id = marketProducts.ProductId
Join markets As market On marketProducts.MarketId = market.Id GROUP BY product.Name
```

Comment: The same problem, fella.